# generate data for multiple architectures with cl.exe

Tags: c, matlab, visual-studio, simd

I'm exporting some MatLab code to C and compiling it with Visual Studio 2013 (cl.exe). I could switch to VS2015 if it helps. The vectorization is very important to me. If I use /O2 it generates the SSE2 code in addition to some fallback code in case it is executed on a non-SSE2 CPU. If I change the architecture to parameter to AVX2, will it generate that code and AVX code and SSE2 code and the fallback code? That's what I want -- run as fast as possible on any CPU. Or will it go straight to the fallback code if the CPU does not support AVX2?

Comment: I don't remember hearing of any compilers doing auto-vectorization with runtime CPU dispatching to pick the best version for the current CPU.  It would be possible for a compiler to do that, but harder than the usual auto-vectorization.  And might require some cooperation from the source code, in terms of running an init function.  There's also the problem of stopping the compiler from going overboard and having too many indirect calls (through function pointers) if it auto-vectorizes a lot of functions.

Comment: Anyway, you can manually set up runtime CPU dispatching to different binaries built from the same code but with different compiler settings.  Also note that SSE2 is baseline for AMD64.  If there aren't any significant speedups from anything less than AVX, then you don't need an SSE4.1 version or whatever, just baseline SSE2 with dispatching to some AVX versions.  (If it's FP code, then AVX2 might not gain anything over AVX1.  so you don't need a separate version for SnB/IvB which have AVX1 only.  But AMD Bulldozer-family can be worse with AVX, partly because of decode bottlenecks.)

Comment: Peter and all, Intel Compiler does "auto-vectorization with runtime CPU dispatching to pick the best version for the current CPU". Use -axcode family of compilation flags, like -axAVX. E.g. for -axAVX compiler will generate "default SSE code path" and secondary "AVX" code path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [Visual C++ Team Blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2014/02/28/avx2-support-in-visual-studio-c-compiler/), the compiler will do neither:

> The compiler will generate code that includes AVX2 and FMA instructions.  The resulting binaries will only run on PCs that support these instructions.  If you run the binaries on an older PC, the program will crash, and display a popup like this:
>
> [image: error popup]